# Why is useEffect() being triggered before the component is rendered?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

My site is using react-bootstrap to manage navigation.

```
const Panes = (props) => (
    <Tabs className="pane" defaultActiveKey="construction" transition={false}>
        <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
            <Home username={props.username} password={props.password} />
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey="positions" title="Positions">
            <Positions />
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey="trades" title="Trade History">
            <Trades />
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey="construction" title="Portfolio Construction">
            <Construction username={props.username} />
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey="risk" title="Risk Analytics">
            <Risk />
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
```

Within the `<Positions />` component I have a simple `useEffect(() => {console.log("THIS IS A TEST")}, [])`

Why do I see "THIS IS A TEST" in the console before I've even clicked on the positions tab? It doesn't seem like that tab has been rendered yet? Do I have some kind of misunderstanding about how hooks are supposed to work?

My ultimate goal is to fetch data only once the user navigates to this `Positions` page. How do I achieve this?

EDIT: I got things working with by setting `unmountOnExit={true}`. This renders only one tab at a time. But ideally, I would like to render the first time I switch to that tab. I thought that is what `mountOnEnter={true}` would do but that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688988/all-react-bootstrap-tabs-render-function-gets-called-every-time-regardless-of-wh).

Turns out that bootstrap renders all the tabs at once. If you set `unmountOnExit={true}` it will only render one at a time.

Though I'm not sure why setting `mountOnEnter={true}` didn't work?

Comment: This might be of use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792720/tabs-only-mount-tab-content-on-the-first-time-it-becomes-active

Comment: Just a suggestion, if you update your question or answer, could you add it to your original question, this way people in the future always know which step you are stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

On the React documentation they have an explanation for this.

*If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and componentWillUnmount combined.*

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

It basically runs with the first render and if you dont give it a dependency array it will run at every render(whenever the state changes).

If you want to fetch the data only one time you should use it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
//fetch data
},[])
```

If you want it to run every time a value changes you should use it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
//fetch data
},[value])
```